# Update single row in JSF / Primefaces datatable using AJAX not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, omnifaces

Why dont't work update single row in this example?

```
    <h:form id="validateFormId">
    <p:dataTable var="elementVal" value="#{testController.players}"
        id="dataTableId" binding="#{dataTableB}" 
        selection="#{testController.selectedPlayers}"
        rowKey="#{elementVal.playerId}" rowIndexVar="idx">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{elementVal.playerName}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="test" process="@this" update=":validateFormId:dataTableId:@row(#{idx})" action="#{testController.triggerElement('ac', elementVal, idx, dataTableB)}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:autoComplete id="fieldA"
                value="#{elementVal.playerPosition}"
                completeMethod="#{autocompleteController.loadSuggestedValues}"
                var="val" itemValue="#{val}" itemLabel="#{val}"
                autoHighlight="false" dropdown="true" my="left bottom"
                at="left top"
                forceSelection="true">
                <p:column>
                    #{val}
                </p:column>
                <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update=":validateFormId:dataTableId:@row(#{idx})"
                    listener="#{testController.triggerElement('ac', elementVal, idx, dataTableB)}" />
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update=":validateFormId:dataTableId:@row(#{idx})"
                    listener="#{testController.triggerElement('ai', elementVal, idx, dataTableB)}" />
            </p:autoComplete>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

when prest "test" button, bean change playerName, but not row update.
tryed with primefaces selector and omnifaces ajax.

```
    public void triggerElement(String event, Player element, int idx, UIData table) {
    System.out.println("trigger event: " + event);
    System.out.println("item: " + element.getPlayerId());
    System.out.println("value: " + element.getPlayerName());


    element.setPlayerName(element.getPlayerName() + "1");

    Ajax.updateRow(table, idx);

}
```

primefaces 5.3, omnifaces 2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

`@row` search expression was not implemented at primefaces 5.3, you have to use primefaces 6.2+